# Simple proof of well-ordering of the class of all sets in the Morse-Kelley theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

As far as I understand, the axiom of global choice implies that the class of all sets can be well-ordered. So I deduce that this is a theorem in the Morse-Kelley theory. I am looking for a simple proof of this fact, can anybody help me?

Comment: Please specify the framework in which you want to have this proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming global choice, there is a global well-order on $V$ (where $V$ is the class of all sets). Let $F \colon V \to V$ be a global choice function. For each ordinal $\alpha$ let $V_\alpha$ be the set of all sets whose $\in$-rank is strictly less than $\alpha$. Let $\mathcal W_\alpha$ be the set of all well-orders on $V_\alpha$ - note that $\mathcal W_\alpha$ is nonempty for $\alpha > 0$. Finally, let $\prec_\alpha = F(\mathcal W_\alpha)$ be the well-order on $V_\alpha$ that is  chosen by $F$.

Now define a relation $\prec \subseteq V \times V$ by $x \prec y$ iff $\operatorname{rank}_\in(x) < \operatorname{rank}_\in(y)$ or [$\operatorname{rank}_\in(x) = \operatorname{rank}_\in(y) =: \alpha$ and $x \prec_\alpha y$]. This defines a strict global well-order.

Comment: Note that MK proves that such a global choice function $F \colon V \to V$ exists: Since $\operatorname{Ord}$ is a proper class, there is an injection $G \colon V \to \operatorname{Ord}$. We may then define $F \colon V \to V$ by $F(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and otherwise let $F(x)$ be the $y \in x$ such that for all $z \in x \colon G(z) \ge G(y)$, i.e. We let $F(x)$ be the unique $y \in x$ such that $G(y)$ is minimal.

Comment: Stefan, I am not a specialist in logic, I need a book where all these terms are explained. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: Why is there an injection $G:V\to\text{Ord}$?

Comment: @Sergei By 'limitation of size' - which is included as an axiom in MK set theory.

Comment: I'm not sure which book to recommend, because I have no idea what your background in set theory is or what your goals in set theory are.

Comment: Actually my knowledge in Set theory is almost completely restricted by Kelley's "General topology". I think I need a book with the explanation of how this "limitation of size" follows from the axioms in Kelley's book.

Comment: I haven't read Kelley's topology book and therefore don't know how he stated the axioms of MK set theory. Furthermore I don't know about an introductory textbook using MK set theory as its axiomatization... It might be worth opening a separate question for this.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. It will take me some time to understand all this.

Comment: If you are assuming there is an injection $G:V\to Ord$, there is a much simpler way to get a well-ordering of $V$ (just use the usual order on $G(V)\subseteq Ord$).

Comment: @Eric Yep, that's easier (and the obvious well-ordering). Thank you.